# Create Direct3DEx interface from C doesn't work

Tags: c, directx-9

i have to admit that i have really strange issue, which im not able to solve by my self. Im trying from few days without success.

My goal is to use Direct3DEx interfaces from C (not C++). I cant use Direct3D because i have to deal with shared resource handles with surfaces from different d3ddevices.

I have no any problems with creating IDirect3DEx from C++, works perfectly. For example this code works as expected

```
IDirect3D9Ex* m_d3d;

Direct3DCreate9Ex(D3D_SDK_VERSION, &m_d3d);

UINT c = m_d3d->GetAdapterCount();

m_d3d->Release();
```

Now im trying to do exactly the same from C,
my code is:

```
void *pd3dll = (void *) LoadLibrary("d3d9.dll");
 UINT count;
 IDirect3D9Ex *pDirect3D9ExInterface;
 HRESULT hr;

 typedef HRESULT (WINAPI *Direct3DCreate9Ex_t)(UINT SDKVersion, IDirect3D9Ex **ppD3D);

 Direct3DCreate9Ex_t Direct3DCreate9ExFunc;

 Direct3DCreate9ExFunc = (Direct3DCreate9Ex_t) GetProcAddress((HMODULE) pd3dll, "Direct3DCreate9Ex");

 hr = Direct3DCreate9ExFunc(D3D_SDK_VERSION, &pDirect3D9ExInterface);

 if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
 {
    count = IDirect3D9Ex_GetAdapterCount(pDirect3D9ExInterface); //crash 

    IDirect3D9Ex_Release(pDirect3D9ExInterface);
 }
```

i dont see absolutly any reason why this piece of code doesnt work.
Please notice that code line:

```
hr = Direct3DCreate9ExFunc(D3D_SDK_VERSION, &pDirect3D9ExInterface);
```

returns S_OK, and when im checking pDirect3D9ExInterface pointer under debuger it looks like a valid pointer.
But this line of code:

```
count = IDirect3D9Ex_GetAdapterCount(pDirect3D9ExInterface); //crash
```

causes my program to crash. When im switching my DirectX9 to debug mode, on VS output window i see after crash, something like this:

> Direct3D9: (ERROR) :Invalid initialization function specified. RegisterSoftwareDevice fails.
>   Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention.

Additionaly if i change this C code to Direct3D initialization (no Direct3DEx) than works without any problems.
What im doing wrong? Where is the catch?
thanks in advance
Jakub

Comment: Why are you using Direct3D9Ex rather than Direct3D 9 or Direct3D 11? Why are you using C instead of C++?

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn please notice as i mentioned in my original post, Direct3D9 doesn't support shared handle for sharing textures, rendertargets, surfaces from another devices. We need to share our textures with external libraries, for ex. Coherent UI Native. Our rendering pipeline is written in C (Direct3D9) and has tons of code, its almost impossible to migrate this library to C++, much easier is to change Direct3D9 to Direct3D9Ex in this lib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be due to a bug in the definition of the `d3d9.h` header file.
A function seems to be left out of the `IDirect3D9Ex` interface that appears in the `IDirect3D9` interface (`IDirect3D9Ex` inherits from `IDirect3D9`).

In `c++` this still works because of inheritance and virtual functions working correctly, in `c`, it doesn't correctly pick up the inheritance due to the way their v-tables are constructed.

Below I've commented out the line that needs to be added to fix this issue (in d3d9.h at line 2044):

```
DECLARE_INTERFACE_(IDirect3D9Ex, IDirect3D9)
{
    /*** IUnknown methods ***/
    STDMETHOD(QueryInterface)(THIS_ REFIID riid, void** ppvObj) PURE;
    STDMETHOD_(ULONG,AddRef)(THIS) PURE;
    STDMETHOD_(ULONG,Release)(THIS) PURE;

    /*** IDirect3D9 methods ***/
    //Add this here: STDMETHOD(RegisterSoftwareDevice)(THIS_ void* pInitializeFunction) PURE;
    STDMETHOD_(UINT, GetAdapterCount)(THIS) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetAdapterIdentifier)(THIS_ UINT Adapter,DWORD Flags,D3DADAPTER_IDENTIFIER9* pIdentifier) PURE;
    STDMETHOD_(UINT, GetAdapterModeCount)(THIS_ UINT Adapter,D3DFORMAT Format) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(EnumAdapterModes)(THIS_ UINT Adapter,D3DFORMAT Format,UINT Mode,D3DDISPLAYMODE* pMode) PURE;
```

You can double check that the functions line up correctly with the returned interface by loading the `d3d9.dll` symbols from the MS servers and comparing the names in the v-table with the values reported. In the image below, the left hand side is the v-table before being fixed, and the right hand side is the v-table after being fixed.

[image: differences between broken and fixed v-tables in debugger]

To get the symbol's from the MS symbol servers:

- start the application and place a breakpoint after `LoadLibrary("d3d9.dll")` has been called
- open up the 'Modules' window (from the menu bar `Debug`->`Windows`->`Modules`)
- Find `d3d9.dll` in the modules list (try typing `d3d9.dll` to quickly go to it)
- Right-click on `d3d9.dll` and click on `Load Symbols From`->`Microsoft Symbol Servers`
- Wait a few seconds for it to download and load the symbols, addresses should then resolve to useful names.

Comment: Note this header bug was fixed in the Windows 10 SDK (10240).The ``D3D9.H`` header bug exists in all versions from Windows 8.1 SDK Spring 2015 or older. It has no impact on C++ usage, only C.

Comment: @Grant Peters, thank you very much. Ofcourse you are right. I want to thank you, for your time and that you wanted to share your deep knowledge with us.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn this is very important information. On my primary dev machine i have Win7+SDK, but on my secondary machine i have full Win10 with Win10SDK i will check that this bug is fixed out of the box, and will let know, because i think its important to let everyone know about this bug, thanks

Comment: Direct3D9Ex was shipped with Windows Vista in late 2006, i.e. a decade ago. The total number of reports from people impacted by the problem of trying to use Direct3D9Ex from C including yours: 2. :)