# Direct3D9Ex function pointers mismatch

Tags: c++, c, directx, direct3d, directx-9

My function calls to D3D9Ex don't work – either they return strange errors or they crash. I have figured out that it's because the vtable is not mapped correctly – the function pointers are mapped to different functions. This is what I see in the VS debugger:
[image: debugger and vtable]

`pD3D` is `LPDIRECT3D9EX`. So, I think that maybe the cause is some version mismatch. At some point they added the `RegisterSoftwareDevice` function but my d3d9.h (and the library?) does not count on it. Anyway, how it should work normally? How does the vtable mapping works so it is aligned with the dll installed on the system?

How do I fix this?

Some more details:

- d3d9.dll is loaded from `C:\Windows\System32\d3d9.dll`
- lib is (probably?) linked from `c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64\d3d9.lib`
- header is from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared\d3d9.h`
- Windows 10, Visual Studio 2019
- The app is 64-bit managed code (.NET+WPF) + unmanaged code: GStreamer pipeline with custom gstd3dwpf element, which is the one trying to access the D3D9Ex functions

Many thanks

Comment: You're looking at a vtable for the CEnum class, not at a IDirect3D9Ex vtable, see here the disassembly https://i.imgur.com/qoTFmw3.png compared with a "vtable for IDirect3DQuery9". This (internal) CEnum class QueryInterface implementation probably points to an offset away from the last IUnknown method (Release). It's not usual, but it's its internal details. It means your calling code is wrong, I guess you're doing a raw C-style casting from IUnknown to IDirect3D9Ex, which is wrong, you must always call QueryInterface to "dynamically cast" in COM.

Comment: Thanks Simon, for your insight. I have updated the image to show also the code. There is really not much what could be wrong about the code, I am just calling Direct3DCreate9Ex as declared in d3d9.h, and header of the function specifically says it is returning IDirect3D9Ex interface. So, I guess there is no need to call QueryInterface. Or is it?

Anyway, yes, the problem could be about the raw C-style casting, you are right, this is C code, not C++. Anyway, all this works if I do the same with D3D9 API instead. Only with D3D9Ex this is happening.

Comment: You're right, this is a bug in Windows 8.1 SDK headers :-) see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35542632/create-direct3dex-interface-from-c-doesnt-work and remarks from (Microsoft's) Chuck Walbourn.

Comment: Omg yes, thank you. Well, this IS (very good) answer, not a comment ;)